# Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_VMM_BUT_AC_CLEAR)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, macintosh

I get this error on my mac when I'm trying to boot up any virtual machine on virtual box on my new MacOS X Yosemite

```
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_VMM_BUT_AC_CLEAR)

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE(0x80004005) 
Component: ConsoleWrap 
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to load VMMR0.r0](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224981/failed-to-load-vmmr0-r0)

Comment: @Tejas No sir that question was incomplete and was put on hold by some users so I thought to put a new complete one

Comment: @UtkarshGupta The recommended approach then is to edit your original question to add the missing information, and ask for it to be re-opened; not delete the original question and ask a new one.

Comment: @StephenKitt Srry, sir I didn't know that

Comment: @UtkarshGupta No problem, you'll know next time :-). Welcome to Unix.SE!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 5.0.2, [this issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14412) may be related to your problem.

Have you tried downgrading to 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problems and just tried the vbox 5.0.0. Every problem is solved.